# I've searched my Mailbox in Outlook and opened one of the emails it found. Which folder is the email in?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

This relates (at least) to Outlook 2013.

When searching an entire Mailbox for email (the default search option, from the Inbox), I found the email I wanted. However, I can't see which folder that email is contained within, either from the preview or when I double click it and open it.

How can I find out which folder the email is in?

After opening the message, I can move it to a chosen folder (and then I know where it is from that point on), but I'd like to know where it is without having to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok lets get this answered now!!

Open the message, click the File menu. Under the info tab on the right hand side next to "Move to Folder", the current folder is displayed.[image: The info menu on a message in Microsoft Outlook]

----old stuff from my first answer below here -----

Try the source listed below. Simply put, you want to see the properties of the message. It should still be similar in Office 2013

[Source](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/outlook-help/i-can-t-find-the-folder-where-a-message-is-stored-HA001140027.aspx) (office 2003)

[Source 2](http://www.adamstauffer.com/finding-which-folder-an-email-is-filed-under-from-within-outlook.htm) (office 2007, may work)

Comment: Thanks, but neither of those methods worked. The latter allowed me to sort by folder, but it didn't display the folder name! I can't add folder to the email list with the field chooser either.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this VBA alternative useful. It displays the folder path and offers to switch to the folder.

http://www.vboffice.net/sample.html?lang=en&mnu=2&smp=65&cmd=showitem

```
Public Sub GetItemsFolderPath()
Dim obj As Object
Dim F As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim Msg as String
Set obj = Application.ActiveWindow
If TypeOf obj Is Outlook.Inspector Then
  Set obj = obj.CurrentItem
Else
  Set obj = obj.Selection(1)
End If
Set F = obj.Parent
Msg = "The path is: " & F.FolderPath & vbCrLf
Msg = Msg & "Switch to the folder?"
If MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
  Set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = F
End If
End Sub
```

Editor and button help - http://www.slipstick.com/developer/how-to-use-outlooks-vba-editor/

Answer (score 0):

1. Search for the email in Outlook 2013
2. Double-click the email to open it in a separate window
3. Click the File tab
4. Click Info along the left (if it's not already selected)
5. Look under Move Item To Different Folder, it should say here where the email is located currently; for

Answer (score 0):

This is an Outlook 2010 solution. Try it in 2013.

With the message opened, open an Advanced Find box. (CTRL+SHIFT+F)

If the same dialog box as 2010 then the folder is shown in the "In:" box. Click on the Browse button to locate the folder.